# Base url en javascript con codeigniter para cargar datatable

Tags: php, codeigniter, datatables

Hola problema es que estoy tratanto de cargar un datatable a través de ajax, pero resulta que me aparece un error 404.

es mi codigo javascript

```
function cargardatos(){
  $('#users-table').DataTable({
              "language": {
              decimal: "",
              emptyTable: "No hay información",
              info: "Mostrando _START_ a _END_ de _TOTAL_ Entradas",
              infoEmpty: "Mostrando 0 to 0 of 0 Entradas",
              infoFiltered: "(Filtrado de _MAX_ total entradas)",
              infoPostFix: ",",
              thousands: ",",
              lengthMenu: "Mostrar _MENU_ Entradas",
              loadingRecords: "Cargando...",
              processing: "Procesando...",
              search: "Buscar:",
              zeroRecords: "Sin resultados encontrados",
              paginate: {
                  first: "Primero",
                  last: "Ultimo",
                  next: "Siguiente",
                  previous: "Anterior"
              }
          },
        "ajax": {
          url: '<?php echo base_url();?>admin/usuarios/userslist',
          type: "POST",
        }
      });
}
```

el error que me aparece es:

```
POST http://localhost/upa/%3C?php%20echo%20base_url();?%3Eadmin/usuarios/userslist 403 (Forbidden)
```

y esta es mi configuracion .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt|css|js|docs|syste)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya encontré la solución, lo que hice fue crear un ruta en *routes.php*

```
$route['admin/getusers'] = 'admin/usuarios/userslist';
```

y luego llamarla desde *ajax* mediante *POST*:

```
function cargardatos(){
  $("#users-table").dataTable().fnDestroy();
  $('#users-table').DataTable({
          "language": {
          decimal: "",
          emptyTable: "No hay información",
          info: "Mostrando _START_ a _END_ de _TOTAL_ Entradas",
          infoEmpty: "Mostrando 0 to 0 of 0 Entradas",
          infoFiltered: "(Filtrado de _MAX_ total entradas)",
          infoPostFix: ",",
          thousands: ",",
          lengthMenu: "Mostrar _MENU_ Entradas",
          loadingRecords: "Cargando...",
          processing: "Procesando...",
          search: "Buscar:",
          zeroRecords: "Sin resultados encontrados",
          paginate: {
              first: "Primero",
              last: "Ultimo",
              next: "Siguiente",
              previous: "Anterior"
          }
      },
      "ajax": {
        url: "admin/getusers",
        type: "POST"
      }
      });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

http://localhost/upa/**%3C**?php

%3C está siendo tomado como ruta del directorio, ese caracter no debería ser codificado a url_encode, eres tú quien conoces la ruta donde deseas enviar la petición, pero asegurate de que ese %3C se utilice literal.